# Not able to pass the dynamic value from eclipse to POM

Tags: maven

Passing the version to POM.xml.

It shows warning.  'version' contains an expression but should be a constant.

I have to remove this.

I have one Ant project and another maven project. I made one runconfiguration for Ant project where I made one variable with some value suppose 13.2.1
by opting external tool configuration that variable come in list now.now able to pass that variable like -Dversion="${versionjar}".
its working perfactly.
since this versionjar is already set in eclipse. I want to use this while I want to run the maven project by runconfiguration.
want to pass in create manage and runconfiguration like in goal section install -Dversion="${versionjar}" but its not working .
I have to set this variable here also by add button. 
How can I pass the variable from eclipse command line like `:install -version="${version}"`? `version` is vailable in eclipse variable list while `"${version}"` is properly send to pom when it is hard coded. 
`"${version}"` is not resolving when send in goals section of run configuration

I'm facing problem when passing the eclipse variable from command line         configuration.

**in POM**

```
<version>${version}</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you have tried?

Comment: @JFMeier ,

can u pls look this issue now?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow your explanation. I need a step by step example.